# How to draw polymers in ConTeXt mkIV with chemfig?

Tags: context, chemfig

I would like to draw polymers with chemfig, using ConTeXt. In chemfig's documentation, we find a solution defining a macro that works well on LaTeX, but not compatible with ConTeXt (I use the mkIV version).
Does anyone know how to convert the macro to make it compatible ?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which macro is this exactly?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. section 12.5 *Draw a polymer element*. The example code defines a `\setpolymerdelim` and a `\makebraces` macro for adding parentheses or brackets to a chemical formula.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ConTeXt, but either way you should add a complete (non-working) example. E.g. the necessary definitions, `\starttext`, an example polymer, `\stoptext`. I think `\newcommand` is a LaTeX thing, so you probably need `\def` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the example from the `chemfig` manual ported to ConTeXt.  Because I'm using another font all the sizes of the delimiters are off, but it should be easy to adjust them.

```
\usemodule[chemfig]

\def\setpolymerdelim#1#2{%
  \def\delimleft{#1}%
  \def\delimright{#2}%
}

\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{%
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]%
      {$\expandafter\left\delimleft\vrule height \delimhalfdim depth \delimhalfdim width 0pt\right.$};%
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]%
      {$\left.\vrule height \delimhalfdim depth \delimhalfdim width 0pt \expandafter\right\delimright_{\rlap{#3}}$};%
  }%
}

\setpolymerdelim()

\starttext

Polyéthylène:
\chemfig{\vphantom{CH_2}-[@{op,.75}]CH_2-CH_2-[@{cl,0.25}]}
\makebraces[5pt,5pt]{\!\!n}{op}{cl}

\blank[big]

Polyvinyl chloride:
\chemfig{\vphantom{CH_2}-[@{op,.75}]CH_2-CH(-[6]Cl)-[@{cl,0.25}]}
\makebraces[5pt,25pt]{\!\!\!n}{op}{cl}

\blank[big]

Nylon 6:
\chemfig{\phantom{N}-[@{op,.75}]{N}(-[2]H)-C(=[2]O)-{(}CH_2{)_5}-[@{cl,0.25}]}
\makebraces[30pt,5pt]{}{op}{cl}

\blank[big]

Polycaprolactame:\setatomsep{2em}
\chemfig{[:-30]-[@{left,.75}]N(-[6]H)-[:30](=[2]O)--[:30]--[:30]--[@{right,0.25}:30]}
\makebraces[5pt,25pt]{\!\!\!n}{left}{right}

\blank[big]

\setpolymerdelim[]
Polyphénylène sulfide:
\chemfig{\vphantom{S}-[@{op,.75}]S-(**6(---(-[@{cl,0.25}])---))}
\makebraces[15pt,15pt]{}{op}{cl}

\blank[big]

\chemfig{-CH_2-CH([6]-CO-NH-CH_2-NH-CO-CH([4]-CH_2-)([0]-[@{downleft,0.8},2]CH_2
-CH([2]-CO-NH_2)-[@{downright,0.3},2]CH_2-[,1.5]C?H-))-[@{upleft,0.8},2]CH_2
-CH([6]-CO-NH_2)-[@{upright,0.3},2]CH_2-[,1.5]CH([6]-CO-NH-CH_2-NH-C?O)-}
\makebraces[5pt,40pt]{n}{upleft}{upright}
\makebraces[38pt,7pt]{n}{downleft}{downright}

\stoptext
```

[image]